# Mapbox map not showing

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I've started replacing Google maps after they announced a change in their policy.
However, the very first attempt to follow Mapbox example did not render the map - only the container with Mapbox logo and information icon are visible.
Any ideas what may be wrong?
The map is not showing up in both Chrome and Firefox, so this is not a browser issue. Mapbox own example renders in both and my access token is valid.
I am also happy to consider an alternative API if it has a great support from this forum.

These lines were added to the bottom of the head section:

```
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.45.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
      <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.45.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
```

And here is the actual code to create the map:

```
<div id = "googleMap"> </div>
   <script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = '<MyAccessToken>';

    var monument = [51.5220163 , -0.1404545];
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'googleMap',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
    center: monument,
    zoom: 16
});
</script>
```

And here is the CSS for the div to complete the picture:

```
#googleMap {

    width: 49%;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    max-height: 60%;
 }
```

There are no console messages either.

Answer (score 4):

Solved!
Unlike Google [Latitude, Longitude] Mapbox uses [lng, lat].

And if you wish to add a simple marker, the full working code is:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'MyAccessToken';

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'googleMap', // container id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9', // stylesheet location
    center: [-0.1404545, 51.5220163], // starting position [lng, lat]
    zoom: 16 // starting zoom
});

  // create the marker
    new mapboxgl.Marker()
    .setLngLat([-0.1404545, 51.5220163])
    .addTo(map);
```

Loading is much slower than with Google though and documentation is less clear.

Answer (score 2):

what I simply do is to add this line of css to my class or id;

```
#googleMap{position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had an issue with the map not showing up.  It was showing up as a grey box, the right size, but just grey.  I am developing a web based JS application.

Test Cases:

- On localhost it was fine.
- On localhost:8080 it was fine.
- On mydomain with my PC/Chrome it was fine.
- On mydomain, with an old iPad it was fine when accessing it.
- On mydomain, with my iPhone it was just NOT-NOT-NOT working.

Turns out the MapBox "Restricted URLs" that are set when create your "Access token" may need adjustment.

I had to add both "https://mydomain/" and "https://mydomain/index.html", for it to work on all client browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

```
npm uninstall react-map-gl

npm cache clean --force

npm install react-map-gl //to re-install react-map-gl.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).